# System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached

Tags: apex, queueable-interface

I have two Queueable classes, I am trying to execute them by chaining them.
First approach was to calling second queueable from first class.

But, it gives me `System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached.` error in test class.

My Apex classes version is 40.0

**Class 1:**

```
public with sharing class QueueableClass1 implements Queueable{
    public QueueableClass1(){}

    public void execute(QueueableContext context){}
}
```

**Class 2:**

```
public with sharing class QueueableClass2 implements Queueable{
    public QueueableClass2(){}
    public void execute(QueueableContext context){}
}
```

**Method:**
The following execution works, but I am looking for chaining queueable jobs.

```
public void processQueues(){
    System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass1());
    System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass2());
}
```

Below code gives "**System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached**." error in test class.

```
public with sharing class QueueableClass1 implements Queueable{
    public QueueableClass1(){}

    public void execute(QueueableContext context){
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass2());    
    }
}
```

**Test Class:** The test class has following syntax.

```
@isTest
public class MyClass_Test {

    @testSetup
    static void createData(){
        // created sample data       
    }
    
    static testMethod void test_processQueues() {
        
        Test.startTest();
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.processQueues(); // This method consist of first Queueable Job. And Second Job has been chained into the first job
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Just wanted to know, Am I doing anything wrong here? I am looking for execution of second class when first class has finished its operation.

Comment: Is the error only specific to Test class ?Do you receive error in actual class ?

Comment: can you provide test class too ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava This error is specific to test class. Actual class is working as expected.

Comment: I think Alexander has the answer for you .Looks like apex test does not support this .

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The next lines on [salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) documentation about `Queueable` interface say the following

> You can’t chain queueable jobs in an Apex test. Doing so results in an
> error. To avoid getting an error, you can check if Apex is running in
> test context by calling Test.isRunningTest() before chaining jobs.

So to test funcionality you can simulate chaining:

```
QueueableClass1 first = new QueueableClass1();
first.execute(null);
//Asserts go here
QueueableClass2 second = new QueueableClass2();
second.execute(null);
//Asserts go here
```

Do not run code above between `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`, as this  will cause to do a try of chaining second class (and this will result in error)

according to Adrian's suggestion about `Test.isRunningTest()` add testvisible Boolean field, that allow you to have flexible control of behavior of class:

```
public with sharing class QueueableClass1 implements Queueable{
    @testVisible
    private static Boolean doChainJob = true;

    public QueueableClass1(){}

    public void execute(QueueableContext context){
        if(doChainJob) {
            System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass2());    
        }
    }
}
```

Then to test it without `Test.isRunningTest()`

```
@isTest
static void testFirstQueueable(){
    QueueableClass1.doChainJob = false;
    Test.startTest();
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass1());
    Test.stopTest();
    //Asserts goes here
}
```

Comment: I tend to prefer a `@TestVisible static Boolean` flag to control this sort of behavior for a bit more flexibility. Though I just avoid calling `Test.isRunningTest()` if it's even remotely possible.

Comment: Alexander, @AdrianLarson, Test class is working now, Thanks for your help :)