# Using Finalizers to Work Around Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2?

Tags: apex, queueable-apex, transaction-finalizers

I was testing `Finalizer` interface with Queueable apex and I think it can also be used to overcome this error: `System.LimitException: Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2`

I created a class `QueueTest`

```
public with sharing class QueueTest implements Queueable, Finalizer{

    private List<List<String>> strings;
    public QueueTest(List<List<String>> strings){
        this.strings = strings;
    }
    public void execute(FinalizerContext param1) {
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueTest1());
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext param1) {
        QueueTest queueTest = new QueueTest(strings);
        System.attachFinalizer(queueTest);
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueTest1());
        System.debug('Queueable executed');

    }
}
```

and here I am firing two Queueable calls from same `QueueTest` class. And I dont see any error.

But when I try to fire same back to back queueable from same `execute` method I get the error `Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2`.

Theoretically both are same, right? Or was finalizer created to overcome such limitations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finalizer was meant to handle LimitException situations in general (too much CPU, heap, etc), as well as any uncaught exceptions, so you can recover from the situation. It is not meant to be a workaround for the too many jobs situation specifically. Note that the Finalizer itself is limited to only one additional action (a Batchable, Queueable, or @future).

Inside the execute(QueueableContext) method, execute(BatchableContext), and @future methods, you are limited to just one Queueable job per execute. If you need to do more than one Queueable in an execute, use a Scheduled job if you can, as those have normal synchronous limits (e.g. 50 Queueable/@future, multiple batches, etc).

Comment: so if i am using queueables to update readonly records in the after trigger and more then 201 records are being updated, thereby causing 2 jobs to enqueue, i can over come this simply by schedualing my queueables instead?

Comment: @Dane You can't schedule queueable. Once you've gone to running DML in asynchronous code, any further asynchronous code must be coordinated to avoid the limit of just one async transaction. I address this concern [on this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/188792/2984) that may be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your contributions are amazing.