# System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached. while writing in test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, exception, queueable

I've got a requirement to perform queueable apex in a trigger my class working fine, but while writing a test class for queueable apex I'm getting an exception. Could anybody can help me.

```
Trigger example on opportunity(After update){
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        System.enqueuejob(new  Oppty_TargetHandlerContainer(Trigger.old));
}
if(Trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
           System.enqueuejob(new  Oppty_TargetHandlerContainer(Trigger.new));
 }

}
```

This my test class

```
@isTest
public class Oppty_TargetHandlerContainerTest {
//varibale Declaration

static void init(){
    //Initializing the data
    }

    //}
}

//Method to cover opportunity handler.
static testMethod void opportunityTriggerMethod1(){
  init();
  Test.startTest();
   System.enqueuejob(new  Oppty_TargetslogicHandler(opplist));
  Test.stopTest();
  Test.startTest();
   System.enqueuejob(new  Oppty_TargetHandlerContainer(opplist));
  Test.stopTest();
}  
}
```

The following are the my queueable classes

```
public class Oppty_TargetHandlerContainer implements Queueable {
@Testvisible
private List<Opportunity> optylist;
public Oppty_TargetHandlerContainer(List<Opportunity> optys) {
    this.optylist = optys;
}
public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
    System.enqueueJob(new Oppty_TargetslogicHandler(optylist));
}
}
```

Logic queueable class

```
public class Oppty_TargetslogicHandler implements Queueable {
//Variable declaration
public Oppty_TargetslogicHandler(List<Opportunity> optys) {
    //storing data in variables
}
public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
    updating some other object,
    there is a recursive trigger

}
}
```

Comment: I tried solutions what you guys are suggested me, Could you help to resolve this problem?, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited my answer below - did the two separate methods work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
@isTest
public class Oppty_TargetHandlerContainerTest {
//varibale Declaration

static void init(){
//Initializing the data
}

//}
}

//Method to cover opportunity handler.
static testMethod void opportunityTriggerMethod1(){
  init();
  Test.startTest();
  Oppty_TargetslogicHandler op=new Oppty_TargetslogicHandler(opplist);
  //opplist is nothing but list of optys
  op.execute(null);
  Test.stopTest();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In your `Oppty_TargetHandlerContainerTest:: opportunityTriggerMethod1()` test method, you are running two asynchronous jobs, which is not allowed in a single test method.  Only one job can be run per test method.

Put each job into a separate test method function and it should work.

**EDIT**

The code should look something like this:

```
static testMethod void opportunityTriggerMethod1(){
   init();

   Test.startTest();
   System.enqueuejob(new  Oppty_TargetslogicHandler(opplist));
   Test.stopTest();
}

static testMethod void opportunityTriggerMethod2(){
   init();

   Test.startTest();
   System.enqueuejob(new  Oppty_TargetHandlerContainer(opplist));
   Test.stopTest();

    // Optional Assert methods to confirm functionality
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Brian Miller, I added Following method to the my code still i'm facing same problem,    static testMethod void opportunityTriggerMethod2(){
           opportunityTriggerMethod1();
           Test.startTest();
            System.enqueuejob(new  Oppty_TargetHandlerContainer(opplist));
             Test.stopTest();
        }

Comment: Don't call `opportunityTriggerMethod1()` within that testMethod.  Have two completely separate test methods.  See the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you can't chain queueable jobs while testing in Apex.
Please refer to this [System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181233/system-asyncexception-maximum-stack-depth-has-been-reached][1])

Comment: Tyhanks for your response @Vincenzo Laudato, I tried it, I got exception like this Constructor not defined: [Oppty_TargetslogicHandler].<Constructor>().