Maximum stack depth has been reached when testing
I'm in rather desperate need of some advice in regards to testing chained asynchronous methods. However I write the test I can't seem to escape the 'Maximum stack depth' error.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
I have an admittedly rather obscure set of triggers/classes handling the suppression of leads that share contact details. I'm still new to Salesforce so this perhaps, (most definitely not), was not the best way to do it. However, this is the problem I am now stuck with, and as always it all comes apart when it comes to testing.
This is just one of the triggers that participate in this charade, the others have a similar setup.
trigger HandleLeadSuppressionTrigger on Lead (after insert, after update) {

    Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {
            if (lead.Related_Account__c != null || lead.Email != null || lead.Phone != null || lead.Related_Contact__c != null || (lead.PostalCode != null  && lead.Company != null)) {
                leadIds.add(lead.Id);
            }    
        }
        
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            Lead oldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id);
            if ((lead.Related_Account__c != null && lead.Related_Account__c != oldLead.Related_Account__c)
                || (lead.Email != null && lead.Email != oldLead.Email) 
                || (lead.Phone != null && lead.Phone != oldLead.Phone) 
                || (lead.Related_Contact__c != null && lead.Related_Contact__c != oldLead.Related_Contact__c) 
                || ((lead.PostalCode != null && lead.PostalCode != oldLead.PostalCode) && (lead.Company != null && lead.Company != oldLead.Company))) {
                leadIds.add(lead.Id);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    if (!leadIds.isEmpty()) {
        if(Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs() - Limits.getQueueableJobs() > 0) {
            System.enqueueJob(new SuppressionQueue(null, null, null, leadIds));
        }    
        else {
            String sec = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().second());
            String min = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().minute() + 1); 
            String hour = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().hour());
            String day = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().day());
            String month = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().month());
            String year = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().year());
            String cronExp = sec + ' ' + min + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ? ' +year;
            System.schedule('Lead Suppression Job ' + Datetime.now(), cronExp, new SuppressionScheduler(null, null, null, leadIds));
        }
    }

And here are the async classes, one Queueable, one Schedulable that orchestrate this hellish endeavor:
public class SuppressionQueue implements Queueable {

    Set<Id> accountIds;
    Set<Id> contactIdsInherit;
    Set<Id> contactIdsApply;
    Set<Id> leadIds;

    public SuppressionQueue(Set<Id> accountIds, Set<Id> contactIdsInherit, Set<Id> contactIdsApply, Set<Id> leadIds) {
        this.accountIds = accountIds;
        this.contactIdsInherit = contactIdsInherit;
        this.contactIdsApply = contactIdsApply;
        this.leadIds = leadIds;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext QC) {
        if (accountIds !=null && !accountIds.isEmpty()) {
            if(accountIds.size() > 1) {
                Database.executeBatch(new ApplyAccountSuppressionBatch(accountIds));
            } else {
                if(Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs() - Limits.getQueueableJobs() > 0) {
                    System.enqueueJob(new ApplyAccountSuppression(accountIds));
                } 
                else {
                    Database.executeBatch(new ApplyAccountSuppressionBatch(accountIds), 1);
                }
            }
        } 
        etc...
    }

public class SuppressionScheduler implements Schedulable  {

    Set<Id> accountIds;
    Set<Id> contactIdsInherit;
    Set<Id> contactIdsApply;
    Set<Id> leadIds;

    public SuppressionScheduler(Set<Id> accountIds, Set<Id> contactIdsInherit, Set<Id> contactIdsApply, Set<Id> leadIds) {
        this.accountIds = accountIds;
        this.contactIdsInherit = contactIdsInherit;
        this.contactIdsApply = contactIdsApply;
        this.leadIds = leadIds;
    }

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        if(accountIds != null && !accountIds.isEmpty()) {
            System.enqueueJob(new SuppressionQueue(accountIds, null, null, null));
        }
        else if (contactIdsInherit != null && !contactIdsInherit.isEmpty()) {
            System.enqueueJob(new SuppressionQueue(null, contactIdsInherit, null, null));
        }
        etc...
    }
}

Each Object essentially has two classes that that carry out the DML; a Queueable class that operates on single records and a Batchable. (Which also acts as the backup for the single record if for some reason the scheduled queue can't enqueue it)
Hopefully the process makes sense. If you want me to provide the main classes for more context I can do but I thought this should be enough info for the purposes of setting up the test.
P.S. Here is a basic test that even fails for this reason just because of the related contact being inserted.
@isTest
public class TestSuppressionHandling {

    @isTest 
    static void testAccountSuppression() {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert a;  

        Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Test', AccountId=a.Id);
        insert c;

        Test.startTest();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}

Thanks in advance.

Do you find something useful in this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181233/system-asyncexception-maximum-stack-depth-has-been-reached ?

@OleksandrBerehovskyi Hi, I did look at that post already and tried to implement the suggestion without any luck. The problem is, just inserting an account and then a contact related to that account will throw this error because the insertion of the contact triggers one of the classes due to it's relation to the account.

Well, the responses have been flooding in.
In the meantime, I refactored and removed the SuppressionQueue class that was in the end was unnecessary. Since the classes doing the DML were Queueable themselves, I could modify the logic and calls in the Triggers and SuppressionScheduler class to call them directly when possible. So the problem this post was for no longer exists since I'm no longer chaining Queueables.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Note that that is one on the "canned" responses that people can use when looking at a post in one of the review queues. That said, going into greater detail about how you "unwound" the async calls could prove useful to other people.
